# Type not being imported properly

Tags: c++, windows, ntdll

I have this code

```
EXTERN_C PEB* NTAPI RtlGetCurrentPeb(VOID);
```

The last compile this worked fine without issue, however now its telling me that **PEB** is an unknown type even though I'm importing **winternl.h** and I havent changed anything that I can think of to relate to this.

When looking at the definition of **winternl.h** I can see that it seems to only contain definitions for x32 bit however this is strange as I've only ever compiled this project in x64.

Comment: Copying over that class and compiling it in a fresh project works fine without any of the errors. Imports are the same and so is the code, really not sure whats causing this. I did do some messing around with additional include directories however its compiled fine since I did those changed. The only difference is I've added a brand new class but that shouldnt of affected this one?

Comment: For some reason in the faulty project _WIN32_WINNT isnt defined at all causing winternl.h to not import anything. I havent explicitly defined it in either project though so I'm still not sure